# Stripe Token and Charge Api vs Stripe paymentIntent api

Tags: stripe-payments

I am new to stripe and going to use stripe token/charge api but the stripe document says the paymentIntent api is the new way to go. Can I use anyone of this or PaymentIntent is the best to use.

I am building a website for business and needed stripe for accepting payments. It has shopping cart. It's pretty basic.

Could anyone help which one should I go with.

Comment: If Stripe says use the Payment Intents API, then I would use the Payment Intents API.

Comment: That's right. But I am worried about something with PaymentIntent api since the object's key will be used to complete the payment via javascript What if someone embeds their own key which has lesser amount in it and proceed through the javascript. As we created the key in server side and stored it in html to be later used in javascript. But what if someone creates their own payment object with lesser amount and use that key in out javascript to proceed

Answer (score 5):

If you are starting out fresh and don't have anything built yet, use the PaymentIntents API. The PaymentIntents API is the newer API that has features that the Charge API doesn't. For instance, PaymentIntents are [fully SCA ready](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication). The Charge API will continue to function, but Stripe is heavily investing in PaymentIntents as the integration path going forward.

Comment: That's right. But I am worried about something with PaymentIntent api since the object's key will be used to complete the payment via javascript What if someone embeds their own key which has lesser amount in it and proceed through the javascript. As we created the key in server side and stored it in html to be later used in javascript. But what if someone creates their own payment object with lesser amount and use that key in out javascript to proceed.

Comment: If you're worried about people gaming your system to pay less for products than they should, then you should make sure to do purchase fulfillment when a PaymentIntent is complete. Check the amount paid, compare it to the amount they should have paid and handle if there's a discrepancy. Also bear in mind that you can only create a PaymentIntent on the server with a secret key. So if someone is able to use your secret key to create a PaymentIntent with a custom amount, that's a whole different problem you need to solve.